# Cannot get simple Angular controller to display a value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

It is not my first time dealing with [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) controllers, but for some reason this one refuses to work as expected. I get the feeling that I've forgotten something very basic here, but have no idea what.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    Hola mundo.
    <div ng-controller="MyFirstCtrl as firstCtrl">
        Dentro de controller 1. Nombre: {{nombre}} <br> Propiedad: {{propiedad}} <br>
    <input type="button" ng-click="setea()" value="Setea">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
app.controller("MyFirstCtrl",function() {
   this.nombre ='Me';
   this.propiedad ='Value';

    var setea = function(){
       alert('In function');
       this.nombre ='Another value';
       this.propiedad ='Another Property';
    };
});
```

I believe Angular is loading correctly, because I don't see any errors on my console and the template values do not appear as {{nombre}} and {{propiedad}}. Instead they appear as blank. If I initialize these properties using ng-init, they display correctly. I've tried this in both Angular 1.2 and 1.3 with the same result.

Comment: use `$scope` instead `this` or call via your controller, i.e `firstCtrl.nombre`

Comment: Using `this` is fine if its assigned to something when using controllerAs syntax. i.e `var vm = this;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use $scope as other says.
I think it's better with the `this` keyword.

You need to prefix your bindings to the controller `firstCtrl.` when you are doing `controller as ctrl`

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    Hola mundo.
    <div ng-controller="MyFirstCtrl as firstCtrl">
        Dentro de controller 1. Nombre: {{firstCtrl.nombre}} <br> Propiedad: {{firstCtrl.propiedad}} <br>
    <input type="button" ng-click="firstCtrl.setea()" value="Setea">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've done it this way before, but this time this isn't working.

Comment: I got it to work with this approach. Guess I must've misspelled something before.

Answer (score 1):

angular properties are bound through the scope:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
app.controller("MyFirstCtrl",function($scope) {
   $scope.datos.nombre ='Me';
   $scope.datos.propiedad ='Value';

    var $scope.setea = function(){
       alert('In function');
       $scope.datos.nombre ='Another value';
       $scope.datos.propiedad ='Another Property';
    };
});
```

that will set the values on `$scope`, which is then used as the context to bind to the template.

You also need to put setea on the $scope (hadn't realized until I saw the comment on the other answer. While the text below may not apply to you're case, I'm leaving it in as an angular good practice).

### **not relevant but good practice nonetheless**

You also need to bind to an object (in this case datos), because of the way javascript handles primitives, you need to have an object so angular does `read(datos).write(nombre)` and `read(datos).write(propiedad)` in you're case. you can find more info about this [here](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/) (the first antipattern describes the issue and provides links to in-depth articles about it).

You're template would now look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    Hola mundo.
    <div ng-controller="MyFirstCtrl as firstCtrl">
        Dentro de controller 1. Nombre: {{datos.nombre}} <br> Propiedad: {{datos.propiedad}} <br>
    <input type="button" ng-click="setea()" value="Setea">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I said to SatPal, this is only working for me with the initial values. Clicking on the button does not update my page.

Comment: put a dot in you're bindings (updating answer now...)

Comment: Using `this` is fine if its assigned to something when using controllerAs syntax. i.e `var vm = this;`

Comment: true, but the point is you can't declare a function locally and have it execute from the markup. Furthermore assigning the vars to the controller instead of the scope feels less intuitive and shareable to me, which is why I chose to go this route in my answer

Comment: I used to think the same until I changed to follow some ones style guide for angular. Having a variable for vm = view model while scope is left for watch/broadcast etc. Makes it easier to understand imo.

Comment: What got me was that I have done this before, and never had to use $scope. Is anything assigned into the $scope object globally shared?

Comment: no, but any var declared locally won't be available outside the function you declare it, I suspect you've used `this.func` previously to declare your functionality

Comment: Yes, I have. I finally got it to work without using $scope. Sorry I didn't mark yours as the answer, but I upvote for the extra info. The whole purpose of this exercise, is, indeed to learn the use $scope, so the info will come in handy.